# Excel match and sum multiple returns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

How can I take data from 1 spreadsheet and match it to another spreadsheet - then sum multiple returns in the same cell.
For example - One spreadsheet has 100 as identifying number - then search for 100 on the other spreadsheet - it has multiple matches - then next to each of the 100's I would like to take the cell next to it and sum/combine all those results back to the original spreadsheet?  I have tried VLOOKUP but it will only return the first result and won't combine the multiple results
Example: 100 - 20
200 - 10
100 - 30
400 - 500
100 - 25
I want to return in the original spreadsheet the value of the 100's summed (20+30+25) or 75????

Comment: Sounds like SUMIFS() will work for what you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can try the SUMPRODUCT function, you should provide a sample here.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to count them and multiply by the value being matched. So, say you have a file with 181 matches to the value 100. You might set up the following formula, placing the match value of 100 in cell A1 for easy changing when wishing to look at other values:

```
=COUNTIF('[Other Spreadsheet.xlsx]'!$C2:$C4001,  A1)  *  A1
```

No need to sum anything as they are all the same. Simply count, then multiply that by the value counted.

It will be faster than any other formula as it has to examine each cell to test their values for use, but so does every other function. But then it is done and you have one multiplication to finish it off. All the others must operate on all values found. It ain't much, nowadays, to be sure, but if the other file is big, and/or is not open, it might become noticeable.